# change sandbox mode to production mode in paypal without changing the code?

Tags: ios, paypal

I have been using PayPal Developer for ios and the app that I have created has already been published. I now realize that the app was still in sandbox mode for PayPal, How can I switch it out of Sandbox mode without resubmitting the app?

Edit: I have been doing some research and realized that I had to change my initialize with client ID's to the following.

```
PayPalMobile.initializeWithClientIds(forEnvironments: [PayPalEnvironmentProduction: "my client ID for production", PayPalEnvironmentSandbox: "my client ID for SandBox"])
```

Sadly when I run it on the simulator it still uses mock data. I don't think that I am using any endpoints, so as my research would tell me this is all that I have to do. Is there another step? Am I doing this step incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

From what I know you have to update your PayPal endpoints from the Sandbox to the PayPal production servers. [PayPals Documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/goingLive/)

Comment: Okay, thanks. I still don't understand steps four and five though. I am quite new to this and don't entirely understand it.

Comment: I think this checklist should answer your question. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/goingLive/#checklist